# How to add TDS support to tshark?

Tags: packet-capture, packet-analyzer, tshark

How to add TDS (knowledge about MS SQL Server packets' structure) support for tshark?

Currently, the situation is this:

```
root@DEV:/# tshark -d . 2>&1| grep -i tds
root@DEV:/#
```

I.e: tshark does not recognize tds protocol.

Comment: It's already there; which versions of Wireshark and SQL Server are you using?